# VBA FormulaArray not working with Replace Function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a rather large array formula that I need to paste into a cell, but can't without breaking it down to a shorter string.

I have no idea why I'm getting this error... I have the below code, but when I execute, a "Unable to set FormulaArray property of the Range class" error on row 10 on the .FormulaArray row. I know this can be related to length of the string, but I checked that the length (after all the variables are assigned) was 255 or less and it was only 188 characters long.

I'm sure it's an easy fix... but please help!

```
Dim titlerange As Long
Dim TN As String
titlerange = Range("'Back End Lookups and Valiations'!L10000").End(xlUp).row

'----Update Hires----
Dim PT1 As String
Dim PT2 As String

PT1 = "=SUM(COUNTIFS('Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx'!Table38[Job Title],'Back End Lookups and Valiations'!$L$2:$L$" & titlerange & ",'Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx'!Table38[Column2],'Data Snapshot'!L$118,YYYY"
PT2 = """'Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx'!Table38[Column1],'Data Snapshot'!$K119,'Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx'!Table38[International Transfer Filter],""OK""))"""

With Range("L119")
    .FormulaArray = PT1
    .Replace What:="YYYY", Replacement:=PT2, LookAt:=xlPart
End With
```

I was able to get this to work by using a SumProduct instead.

```
Dim titlerange As Long
titlerange = Range("'Back End Lookups and Valiations'!L10000").End(xlUp).row

'----Update Hires----
Range("L119").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS('Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx'!Table38[Job Title],'Back End Lookups and Valiations'!$L$2:$L$" & titlerange & ",'Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx'!Table38[Column2],'Data Snapshot'!L$118,'Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx'!Table38[Column1],'Data Snapshot'!$K119,'Headcount Model - Raw Data.xlsx'!Table38[International Transfer Filter],""OK""))"
```

Comment: PT1 is not a valid formula

Comment: Use SUMPRODUCT and it will be a regular formula without the 255 character restraint and can be entered as one string.

Comment: Scott, your solutions worked! Thank you!